Python tkinter will not delete an entry, will only delete all but the last character
This is my first time coding, please go easy.
I'm trying to make an app that will take 5 different entries. Once a button is pressed, I want these entries to be cleared. I'm currently testing with just one - "lditime". I have the input set so that it only accept (XX:XX:XX) and no more characters, and no backspaces, where X is a digit.
I've got over a thousand lines of code for the whole game so I've done my best to pick the relevant stuff out, let me know if more is needed.
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

def validate_time(inputtime):
    if len(inputtime) == 1 and inputtime[-1].isdigit():
        return True
    if len(inputtime) == 2 and inputtime[-1].isdigit():
        return True
    if len(inputtime) == 3 and inputtime[-1] == ":":
        return True
    if len(inputtime) == 4 and inputtime[-1].isdigit():
        return True
    if len(inputtime) == 5 and inputtime[-1].isdigit():
        return True
    if len(inputtime) == 6 and inputtime[-1] == ":":
        return True
    if len(inputtime) == 7 and inputtime[-1].isdigit():
        return True
    if len(inputtime) == 8 and inputtime[-1].isdigit():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def on_validate(P):
    return validate_time(P)

def backandmessage(bs):
    if bs.keysym == "BackSpace":
        return "break"
    messagecheck()  #cmd that is irrelevant

def ldrelease():
    if (len(lditime.get()) == 8 and len(ldilat.get()) == 8 and len(ldilong.get()) == 8 and
            ((ldd1cbv.get() == 1 or ldd2cbv.get() == 1) or ldd3cbv.get() == 1 or ldd4cbv.get() == 1
             or ldd5cbv.get() == 1 or ldd6cbv.get() == 1)):
        lditime.delete(0, 8)
        ldd1.deselect()
        ldd1.configure(state="normal")
        ldd2.deselect()
        ldd2.configure(state="normal")
        ldd3.deselect()
        ldd3.configure(state="normal")
        ldd4.deselect()
        ldd4.configure(state="normal")
        ldd5.deselect()
        ldd5.configure(state="normal")
        ldd6.deselect()
        ldd6.configure(state="normal")


ldi = tk.Label(text="Load Drop Interface", font=("Helvetica", 15))
lditimet = tk.Label(text="Time", font=("Helvetica", 15))
lditime = tk.Entry(validate="key", validatecommand=(window.register(on_validate), "%P"))
lditime.bind("<KeyPress>", backandmessage)
lddrelease = tk.Button(text="Release", font=("Helvetica", 15), command=ldrelease)

window.mainloop()

I have tried using lditime.delete(0, 8) as above, lditime.delete(0, tk.END).
When I use lditime.delete(0, 7) it will clear all but the last character of the entry.
When I get it to print len(lditime.get()) it comes out as 8.
When I print it out character by character, it is as expected (I've been using 12:12:12 as a test).
I have tried using lditime.focus_force() before the deletion.
The deselect statements are running as expected, but just in case I moved the deletion to a different button that has been functioning fine. When I did this, I tried
    print(lditime.get())
    print(len(lditime.get()))
    lditime.delete(0, 8)
    print(lditime.get())
    print(len(lditime.get()))

Which gave me 8, 12:12:12, 8, 12:12:12
When I repeated it with lditime.delete(0, 7) it came out with 8, 12:12:12, 2, 1
I have wasted hours. Please help me.

you may need <KeyRelease> instead of <KeyPress>. As I remeber KeyPress may run code before it puts new char in Entry, and KeyRelease may run code after it put new char in Entry

@furas thanks but still will erase all but the last with 7, none with 8/tk.END. just about to edit to put in the code about the command backandmessage

maybe first use print() to see which part of code is executed, and what you have in variables. Maybe it is executed before tkinter put last char in Entry . Or it execute another function at the same time and it adds last char. if you would create minimal working code then we could test this problem on our computers. Maybe this problem exists only on some systems (WIndows, Linux, MacOS).

When you call lditime.delete(0, 8), the validation function validate_time() will return False because inputtime is empty string. So nothing will be deleted.
You need to return True when inputtime is empty string:
def validate_time(inputtime):
    if len(inputtime) == 0:
        return True
    ...


That did it thank you so much! I felt it might have something to do with that but just couldn't figure it out.

this is a test try this break it down one by one and figure out or write a test script
            import tkinter as tk

            def clear_entry():
                print("Widget state before clear:", entry['state'])  # Check widget state
                print("Content before clear:", entry.get())  # Log content before clearing
                entry.delete(0, tk.END)  # Attempt to clear the entry
                print("Content after clear:", entry.get())  # Log content after clearing

            root = tk.Tk()
            entry = tk.Entry(root)
            entry.pack()
            entry.insert(0, "12:34:56")  # Inserting example data

            clear_button = tk.Button(root, text="Clear", command=clear_entry)
            clear_button.pack()

            root.mainloop()

This script is designed to log important states and content of the entry before and after attempting to clear it, which can help identify issues related to widget state or content management
and here is a possible work around:
            import tkinter as tk

            window = tk.Tk()

            lditime_var = tk.StringVar()
            lditime = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=lditime_var)
            lditime.pack()

            def clear_entry():
                lditime_var.set('')  # Clear the entry by setting its linked StringVar to an empty string

            clear_button = tk.Button(window, text="Clear", command=clear_entry)
            clear_button.pack()

            window.mainloop()

This function sets the content of lditime_var to an empty string. Since lditime is linked to this StringVar, changing the value of lditime_var automatically updates the text displayed in the Entry widget

Thanks but I mentioned in the post I've tried lditime.delete(0, 8), lditime.delete(0, tk.END), and lditime.delete(0, len(lditime.get()). They all just refused to clear it.

Q1: How does the entry behave when you strip down the event bindings and other interactions
Q2: Can you provide more details about what messagecheck() does and any other code that interacts with lditime?
Q3: Are there other parts of your code that might modify or interact with the Entry widget's state or contents outside of the deletion operation?
